KVM/Docking Station for work laptop, working from home
I need a KVM/Docking station for my work laptop, that will preferably also connect my home personal desktop PC.
I'm open to other solutions but this seems like the best option. I want it to be able to charge my laptop. I need to avoid constantly changing wires between work laptop and personal Desktop for my two screens. The Laptop is a Dell Precision 3480. My monitors are currently connected to my home Desktop with an HDMI cable and a DisplayPort cable.
I think it would also be best if it doesn't require installing any additional software, for security reasons. Has anyone got any good suggestions? Also, I'm in the UK, if that's relevant.

I would recommend to use a docking station from Dell itself like the Dell WD19S130W. This will provide power, couple of monitors, USB's and ethernet. All this can be connected to your laptop by plugging in 1 cable. I can't tell if you need to install extra software or not, maybe some drivers from Dell itself to make it work.
